# How to install Open OPC on ubuntu for python support

Tags: pip, open-opc

I am trying to install OpenOPC. So far I tried the following and it shows the following output:

```
tsp@tsp-Inspiron-5558:~/Downloads/OpenOPC-1.3.1$ pip install OpenOPC
Collecting OpenOPC
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement OpenOPC (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for OpenOPC
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
tsp@tsp-Inspiron-5558:~/Downloads/OpenOPC-1.3.1$
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no downloadable packages at [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/OpenOPC) hence `pip` cannot download it. You have to download it from [SF](https://sourceforge.net/projects/openopc/files/openopc/), unpack and install.

Answer (score 0):

For people hitting this question.

With this repo we fixed the installation hassles and updated OpenOpc to recent python versions.

Disclaimer: I am a contributor of that Library

[OpenOpc2](https://github.com/iterativ/openopc2)